# Java date - 12am is stored as 24?

Tags: java, date, calendar, format, simpledateformat

So me and my partner have been working on this project for a while now. We work with dates A LOT in this project, and we recently noticed an issue, and we are rather deep in at this point.

We store our times in SQLlite (Android project) as a formatted string, since a lot of the time they are directly bound to listviews and such.

The problem we noticed, which i found kind of odd, is that that SimpleDateTimeFormat object, when used to format to 24h time (its a medical based project, so 24h time is the convention here) 12:00am-12:59am are formatted to 24:00-24:59, instead of 00:00-00:59...

This isn't too much of an issue until we query the database and order the results by the dates, any data that is between 12:00am and 12:59am will show up at the end of the list, but it should show up at the beginning...

Anyone else encountered this problem? or know a way around it? The best thing possible would be a way to store the data as 00:00 not 24:00.

Cheers

Comment: Storing dates as strings is where you went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I strongly suspect you're using the wrong pattern. We've got to guess as you haven't posted any code (hint, hint), but I *suspect* you're using a pattern such as

```
kk:mm:ss
```

instead of

```
HH:mm:ss
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat broken = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
        broken.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        SimpleDateFormat working = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        working.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

        Date epoch = new Date(0);

        System.out.println(broken.format(epoch));
        System.out.println(working.format(epoch));
    }
}
```

Additionally, as others have pointed out, you shouldn't be storing your values in string format to start with... avoid string conversions wherever you can, as each conversion is a potential pain point.

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm is our format, which explains the issue, should be using HH!

Comment: Also, I know we should have used the miliseconds to store it instead of the strings, but like I said, the project is very deep in at this point, and it is an excessive amount of changes to do at this point. As we are about to enter a beta, we were looking for a temp fix so we can roll this out on time, and in next phase, fully repair the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) about how SQLite stores dates (or doesn't store dates). SQLite doesn't have a "Date" type, so it is stored as a string. You should store your date as an integer (milliseconds), and then you can use date and time functions to pull them out (from the first link).

**From the documentation**

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

I prefer INTEGER / Unix time storage, then use the built in date and time functions to format when pulling from DB.

EDIT: Also, this will take care of sorting. I'm guessing your current "sorting" of the dates in SQLite is string based, which is bad mmmmkay.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format string you are passing to your [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?  According to the docs, using 'H' for the hours should get you 0-23, using 'k' should get you 1-24.